# How to test file response in Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, csv, testing

I have an API that generates and returns a CSV file:

```
def getCSV():
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=export.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response, csv.excel)

    # ... Write some CSV content ...

    return response
```

This works fine when I call it from the browser, but I cannot figure out how to write a test that calls the API and check that the CSV contents are what they should be.

If I:

```
c = Client()
r = c.get('/my/export/api')
print(r.content)
```

That just prints three bytes and is most probably conceptually completely wrong.

How can I get the contents of the CSV file response in my test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Unit Test for testing a file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244220/django-unit-test-for-testing-a-file-download)

Answer (score 17):

[How to read a csv django http response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003220/how-to-read-a-csv-django-http-response)

```
import csv
import io

def test_csv_export(self):

    response = self.client.get('/my/export/api')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    content = response.content.decode('utf-8')
    cvs_reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(content))
    body = list(cvs_reader)
    headers = body.pop(0)

    print(body)
    print(headers)
```